# Inconsistency of one statement implies every statement is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Ok so I was reading Hungerford's book on Abstract algebra and it uses the Bernays-Gödel set theory. In it he presents Russel's Paradox and says that if a statement is both true and false then that can be manipulated to make any statement true. How?

Comment: In classical logic, we have "ex falso quodlibet", $P \land \lnot P \Rightarrow Q$.

Comment: Also related: [Can the principle of explosion be removed from constructive logic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/can-the-principle-of-explosion-be-removed-from-constructive-logic)