# Strong logical system without principle of explosion

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, formal-systems

Are there some logical systems strong enough to contain theorems of first/second order Peano Arithmetic but constructed in such way that principle of explosion does not hold for them?

Comment: You can see [Inconsistent Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/).

Comment: Related: [Can the principle of explosion be removed from constructive logic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/can-the-principle-of-explosion-be-removed-from-constructive-logic)