# $ \models A$ vs. $ A \models$

Tags: logic, notation, definition, propositional-calculus, model-theory

As far as I understand the notion of semantic consequence (denoted by $\models$), $ \models A$ means $A$  is a semantic consequence of the *empty* set. So the "empty space" on the left side of the double turnstile means "empty set".

However, when we take a look at  $A \models $, now that means $A$ is a contradiction, i.e., *everything* is a semantic consequence of $A$. Now the empty space means "everything".

Why is that? Is there any explanation for that difference?

Comment: What was not clear about the two **highly upvoted** answers to your [previous identical post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3635374/semantical-and-syntactical-derivation-notation) ?

Comment: It's not an identical post, I invite you to read it thoroughly. The older post asks what these notations mean, this post asks *why* that is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand this difference, it is better to see these notations in a more general context. Actually, there is a *uniform* explanation for them.

Let $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ be *sets* of formulas. The notation $\Gamma \models \Delta$ means that every structure (in the language $\mathcal{L}$ for the formulas in $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$) that satisfies *all* the formulas in $\Gamma$, satisfies also *at least one* formula in $\Delta$. This is the key semantic notion of *logical consequence*.

Now, what happen if $\Gamma = \emptyset$ and $\Delta = \{A\}$? It is [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) true that every structure satisfies *all* the formulas in $\Gamma$, since $\Gamma$ is empty. Therefore, the notation $\Gamma \models \Delta$, i.e. $\models A$, says that
*every* structure satisfies $A$ (the only formula in $\Delta$), i.e. $A$ is universally *valid* (a tautology in propositional logic).

What happen if $\Gamma = \{A\}$ and $\Delta = \emptyset$? It is necessarily false that a structure satisfies *at least one* the formulas in $\Delta$, since $\Delta$ is empty. Therefore, the notation $\Gamma \models \Delta$, i.e. $A \models \,$, says that
*there is no* structure that satisfies $A$ (otherwise it would satisfy at least one formula in $\Delta = \emptyset$), i.e. $A$ is a *contradiction* (or unsatisfiable).
Moreover, since there is no structure that satisfies $A$, it is also vacuously true that *every* structure that satisfies $A$ satisfies also a formula $B$ *whatsoever*. This is the reason why if $A \models \, $ (i.e. if $A$ is a contradiction) then *everything* is a semantic consequence of $A$: this is the so-called
[principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), aka *ex falso quodlibet*.

---

In model theory, the notation $\Gamma \models \Delta$ is often used in the case $\Delta$ is a singleton, i.e. in the form $\Gamma \models A$. The idea is that $\Gamma$ represents the set of hypotheses and $A$ is the thesis. So, in the literature is not quite common the notation $A \models \,$, but it is not impossible to find it. For instance, if I remember well, Epstein’s textbook *Classical Mathematical Logic: the Semantic Foundations of Logic* uses the notation $A \models \, $.

What I want to stress is that the notations $\models A$ and $A \models \,$ are perfectly consistent and have the general and uniform explanation I sketched above.

Moreover, in proof theory, especially in the [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) for classical logic, it is very natural to deal with objects, called *sequents*, of the form $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ where $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are *finite* sets (or multisets or sequences), possibly empty, of formulas. A sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ intuitively means that there is a derivation from the *conjunction* of the formulas in $\Gamma$ to the *disjunction* of the formulas in $\Delta$, in a derivation system with precise inference rules. Apparently, this *syntactical* notion of sequent has nothing to do with the semantic notion of logical consequence, but according to the [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) and [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) theorems (which holds for many logics, in particular for propositional and first-order classical logic), these two notions coincide, so it is equivalent to say $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ and $\Gamma \models \Delta$, when $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are finite (possibly empty) sets of formulas.

Answer (score 6):

It helps to think of semantic consequence as a disjunction, where the premises are negated and the conclusion is positive:

$A_1, ..., A_n \vDash B$

means

"[For all valuations, ] if $A_1$ and ... and $A_n$ are all true [under that valuation], then $B$ is true [under that same valuation], too"

which can, using the fact that "If X then Y" is in mathematical use equivalent to "either X is not the case or Y is the case", be reformulated as

"either not all of $A_1$ and ... and $A_n$ are true, or $B$ is true"

which is in turn, using the equivalence between "not both X and Y" and "not X or not Y", equivalent to

"not $A_1$ or not ... or not $A_n$, or $B$".

---

Now

$\vDash A$

where there are no (negated) premises and only the (unnegated) conclusion

means

"[For all valuations, ] (nothing) or $A$"

so $A$ is the only option to make the "or"-statement happen -- $A$ must be true under all circumstances, i.e., $A$ is a tautology.

However, if $A$ occurs on the left side of the sequent

$A \vDash$

it is negated, so we have

"[For all valuations, ] not $A$ or (nothing)"

so now "not $A$" is the only option to satisfy the disjunction, meaning that $A$ can only ever be false -- i.o.w., $A$ is a contradiction.