# What if we don't accept ex falso quodlibet?

Tags: natural-deduction

What happens in a logical system if we do not state ex falso quodlibet?

$\bot\rightarrow P$

Comment: I tried to make a search but that did not come up.

Comment: Closely related: [Can the principle of explosion be removed from constructive logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148210/can-the-principle-of-explosion-be-removed-from-constructive-logic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Paraconsistent Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/) for a family of logics that reject *Ex Falso* (aka: *Principle of Explosion*).

See also: Walter Carnielli & Marcelo Esteban Coniglio, [Paraconsistent Logic: Consistency, Contradiction and Negation (Springer, 2016)](https://books.google.it/books?id=VApkDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover),

as well as: Holger Andreas & Peter Verdée (editors), [Logical Studies of Paraconsistent Reasoning in Science and Mathematics (2016, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=7gqkDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).